# 'this' & 'super' keyword usage in Java

Tags: java, this, super

While we are using this/super to call any non static members of a class, JVM creates any object for the corresponding class.

And if I am changing any non static variable in super class using 'super', this  change is also getting reflected in subclass.

```
class A
{
    int i;
}
class Test extends A {
    void test()
    {
        super.i = 10;
        this.i = 8;
        System.out.println("super.i = " + super.i);
        System.out.println("this.i = " + this.i);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test obj = new Test();
        obj.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Using `this` or `super` does not cause any objects to be created.  `this` is inherently present in all instance methods, and `super` is simply a special type of call that uses the superclass's table of methods rather than the current class's table.

Comment: With regard to referencing instance fields, if `int i;` is declared in both classes then two distinct fields are created, and they behave exactly as if they were named, say, `j` and `k`.  If you only have `i` declared in the superclass, however, there is only one instance, and `this.i` and `super.i` reference the exact same field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your question is why the two statements

```
System.out.println("super.i = " + super.i);
System.out.println("this.i = " + this.i);
```

Are both printing the same thing (specifically, `8`).

The reason is that `this.i` and `super.i` are both referring to the same field `i`. The `i` that `Test` has is the one it inherited from `A`. Therefore saying `super.i` is redundant.

Contrast your example with this:

```
public class A{
    int i;
}

public class B extends A{
    int i;

    void test(){
        this.i = 8;
        super.i = 10;
        System.out.println("super.i = " + super.i);
        System.out.println("this.i = " + this.i);
    }
}
```

Here we have *two different fields* named `i`, so just `i` or `this.i` will refer to the field declared in `B`, whereas `super.i` will refer to the `i` declared in `A` that instances of `B` have also inherited.

(Aside: This is a really terrible practice called variable shadowing. Try not to do it whenever possible)

Comment: Nice answer.  The simplest rule to “not do it when possible” is to routinely make attributes of non-`final` classes `private` which is a good idea anyway.